# Get value from a Combobox Binding MVVM not get correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi i made a bindable combobox with MVVM and when i'm trying to get the value of combobox it gets the path of the value ex:I select a name and it return WpfApp1.Parts .

[image: Image with the program]

How can i get the name from combobox as string?

And if enyone know how can i save the combobox that when i add a new value , like when i enter again on the program my last entered value to be there!

View.Parts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Parts : Changed
    {
        public string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }            
        }


    }
}
```

ViewModel.AddViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class AddViewModel : Changed
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Parts> _persons;
        public string names;
        public AddViewModel()
        {
            Persons = new ObservableCollection<Parts>()
             {
                  new Parts{Name="Nirav"}
                 ,new Parts{Name="Kapil"}
                 ,new Parts{Name="Arvind"}
                 ,new Parts{Name="Rajan"}
             };

        }

public ObservableCollection<Parts> Persons
        {
            get { return _persons; }
            set {
                if (_persons != value)
                {
                    _persons = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Persons");
                }
            }
        }
        private Parts _sperson;

        public Parts SPerson
        {
            get { return _sperson; }
            set {
                if (_sperson != value)
                {
                    _sperson = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SPerson");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public AddViewModel addviewmodel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            addviewmodel = new AddViewModel();
            DataContext = addviewmodel;
        }

        public AddViewModel getModel()
        {
            return addviewmodel;
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //textshow.Text = holo.SelectedItem;
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                getModel().Persons.Add(new Parts { Name = cmbtxt.Text});
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindowXaml:

```
 <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="holo"  ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SPerson}"    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="314" Height="27">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox Name="cmbtxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="24,21,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" />

        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Height="49" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="textshow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=SPerson}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="391,104,0,0" Height="33" Width="223"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to the `Name` property of the selected item returned by the `SPerson` property:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textshow" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Text="{Binding Path=SPerson.Name}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="391,104,0,0" Height="33" Width="223"/>
```

What you currently see is the `ToString()` representation of the `Parts` class so the other option would to override this method:

```
public class Parts : Changed
{
    public string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="textshow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=SPerson}"
```

You cannot bind Text property to complex Object like Parts you should bind it to the Name as you did with ComboBox